# Cannot SSH into scale set instances using application gateway

Tags: azure, ssh, azure-application-gateway, azure-vm-scale-set, network-security-groups

I've created a scale-set with two instances and connected the scale-set with application gateway. Now, I want to ssh into the instances but I cannot do it using application gateway. The instances do not have public IP assigned.

I was able to ssh into instances using load-balancer(when scale-set was connected to load balancer).

I tried to create an NSG and associate NSG with application gateway subnet, but still cannot ssh into scale set instances.

How can I ssh into scale set instances that is behind application gateway?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do that, Application Gateway operates on layer 7 (so HTTP), so you are pretty much limited to HTTP traffic only using Application gateway.

You can attach Load Balancer to your scale set and use that only for natting your ssh connections and bypass load balancer for application gateway connections

other options: vpn\jumpbox

Answer (score 0):

Application gateway will be connecting to backend VMs using a different port. I faced this issue, but I was using load balancer. Load balancer was using port 50,000 to connect to my backend instance. I was not able to SSH through port 22 but was able to SSH using port 50,000. You can check which port is application gateway using to connect to backend instance and use that port to SSH. I believe it should work.